# Why does no data show up in the embedded CartoDB map?

Tags: carto, visualisation, embeddable-web-maps

It seems something went wrong with CartoDB. Recently I am trying to embed my visualization into my website. But only comes with a blank map. Then I noticed that the live example from the official website also has the same issue.

Here is the link:
http://cartodb.github.io/cartodb.js/examples/easy.html

Comment: Are you still having trouble with this? I see coloured countries (Europe, Northern Asia) on the link you've provided.

Comment: Same as @BradHards, we see it working here.

Comment: Turns out it only happens when I am using the campus network. It works when I am using cellular network or comcast at my home. That's really weird.